# How to add flutter support for gitlab code editer

Tags: flutter, plugins, gitlab

I need to edit my code in Gitlab and Gitlab default code editor is not showing any suggestions for flutter, dart and is there any way to solve this issue?

 In vsCode editor i added a plugin to do this and is there any option available in Gitlab code editor?